# Positive definiteness of a matrix involving transpose

Tags: matrices

Given

- $A \in R^{n \times n}$,
- $v \in R^n$,
- $\sigma \in R$, $\sigma=\frac{1}{v^T v}>0$,

is
$$B=A A^T - \sigma A v v^T A^T$$
positive definite?

What I currently know is that

- $A A^T$ being positive definite and
- $-\sigma A v v^T A^T$ is a negative semidefinite rank-1 matrix with eigenvalues 0 and $- \sigma v^T A^T A v$.

Additionally, I have the following inequality (forgot whose law that was...)
$$\lambda_{min} (B)\ge \lambda_{min}(AA^T) - \sigma v^T A^T A v$$
with $\lambda_{min}$ being the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix.

Can I say anything about $\lambda_{min} (B)\ge \lambda_{min}(AA^T) - \sigma v^T A^T A v >0$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: not if $A,$ hence $A^T,$ is singular.

Comment: A is regular in my case.

Comment: In that case, you can just find $w^T B w$ for $w$ a column vector, see what happens. Three cases, $w= v,$ next $w \perp v$, if that is not conclusive then $w = v \cos \theta + u \sin \theta,$ where $u \perp v.$

Comment: Hmm, I think I don't understand. I would like to show that B is pos. def. _in general_. Finding one particular vector w, for which it holds, would not help in this case, would it?

Comment: Same idea, $w^T B w,$ first $w = Av,$ next $w \perp Av,$ third a mixeture.

Comment: If $w^T B w > 0$ for all nonzero $w,$ that is positive definiteness.

Comment: If dimension is at least $3$ and $v$ is not an eigenvector of $A,$ I guess you need to work in three directions, two are $v$ and $Av,$ the third is anything orthogonal to both.

Comment: With Av do you mean the v from my B above? Or do you mean some arbitrary vector? If I understand correctly, I have to show _w^T B w >0_ for arbitrary w, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's false. Take two by two $A=I,$ and take the column vector $v = (0,1)^T.$ Calculate $B.$ I was trying to get you to write down some simple 2 by 2 examples to see what actually happens, rather than fiddle with random theorems when you don't actually know the outcome yet. I'll need to look this up, I think it was Olga Taussky-Todd who said that if a matrix statement is false, there is a two by two counterexample.

Comment: Now I get it! :-) I thought you wanted to show that it _is_ actually pos. def.